# Keep Div size same for every different image sizes?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a Gallery Web page and I have different size images stored in local server. What I want is to make my gallery look like this. Simply saying I want to keep Division size same for all image sizes. Also image should cover whole area.

[image: This kind of Gallery]

**What I tried**

I suppose to use PHP to get image locations and do this task. So I'll paste PHP file.

```
<?php
$itemNum =$_POST["itemNum"] ;
$folderName = $_POST["folderName"];

echo '<div class="col-md-4 mix category-a" style="margin:10px;height:300px;width:400px">
                <div class="single-portfolio" style="height:300px;width:400px;overflow: hidden;">
                    <a class="gallery-item" href="gallery/'.$folderName.'/'.$itemNum.'.jpg"><img class="img-responsive"  src="gallery/'.$folderName.'/'.$itemNum.'.jpg" alt="One" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>';
die();
?>?>
```

**My Problem**

This code doesn't do what I want. I tried every way I know to make this possible. Can someone help me to get what I want? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

This is what I got. Can see that size changes according to image size

[image]

Comment: only set `height` and `width` to your `<img>` tag.

Comment: so you want to say that divs height width got changed based on image?

Comment: So you want to have the whole rectangle filled, but keep the aspect ratio? You will have to work with overflows in css.

Comment: @AlivetoDie It changes according to image size. I added an screenshot of my web page.

Comment: Look at use overflow:hidden if you don't want force the resizing of your image. Find css tips for that

Comment: Avoid the evils of inline styling. Add a CSS class. Inline styling isn't always bad, but this is an obvious instance of the benefits of CSS. Add a class to the div and img tags, then you can play with the CSS to find what works best without ever modifying your php code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set max-height and max-width of div and also fix height of image :

```
<div class="single-portfolio" style="max-height:300px;max-width:400px;overflow: hidden;">

<img style="height:300px;width:400px;" class="img-responsive"  src="gallery/'.$folderName.'/'.$itemNum.'.jpg" alt="One" />
```

Comment: What if it's a vertical image?

Comment: @sam1234 check updated and yes this will cause your image stretch issue

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is playing with css and its so easy to apply. You have fixed height of image and that is 400px.

So css for the div will be

```css
.category-a {
  height: 400px;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And your HTML will be like this. Please don't apply inline css as its always bad practice to use like this. instead use class.

```html
<div class="col-md-4 mix category-a">
                <div class="single-portfolio">
                    <a class="gallery-item" href="gallery/'.$folderName.'/'.$itemNum.'.jpg"><img class="img-responsive"  src="gallery/'.$folderName.'/'.$itemNum.'.jpg" alt="One" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```